# BigQuery - how long does it take for a table to show up after "bq load"?

Tags: google-bigquery

Job id:

> bqjob_r6293db3bbc90d36c_0000015cf975dafe_1

It was from running `bq load ... gs://mypath/*.csv ....` command to upload 3900 odd CSV files into one table, total file size around 200GB. the job status shows `DONE`. It's been quite a while, I still don't see it from BigQuery console...

**My question is**: how long should I expect?

Comment: did you reload the page? table should show instantly...

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I did reload. it was not there. I ended up create table from BQ web UI...

Answer (score 0):

As Felipe has pointed out in his comment, it should show up as soon as the load job is finished (unless there were errors of course).

Either:

1. Reload or refresh
2. run `bq ls <project-id>:<dataset>` (you should see your table listed)

Comment: It's weird. I tried several times. No errors, just say DONE.  the table didn't show up at all. not in bq ls either. I ended up creating table using GBQ web UI from exactly the same batch of files and worked

Comment: that makes no sense at all